# Can I mute the playback when using the sox utility to for real time voice changing?

Tags: sox

I'm running the latest version of Ubuntu, and sometimes I like to use the sox utility to change the pitch of my voice by running a command like:

`sox -d -d pitch -500`

When I do this, it plays my own voice back to me as I'm speaking and it's rather annoying. Is there any way I can stop this?